# <audio> tag with PHP variable

Tags: php, html, variables, audio

I am having trouble with PHP playing audio. I am very new to PHP but know a decent amount of HTML. Here is my php code:

```
$r       = mt_rand(1,3);

$authors = array(
1 => 'Sandro Silva & Quintino - Epic (Original Mix)',
2 => 'Sandro Silva & Quintino - Epic (Original Mix)',
3 => 'Sandro Silva & Quintino - Epic (Original Mix)'
);

if ($authors[$r] == 'Sandro Silva & Quintino - Epic (Original Mix)') {
$music  = 'http://4late.nn.pe/loading_screen/Sandro Silva.ogg'
}
```

And my audio block:

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="<?php echo $music;?>" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Any ideas?

ps: The music names won't be the same, its just an example.

**EDIT:** I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in index.php on line 31`

Comment: You need to add a semicolon after `$music  = 'http://4late.nn.pe/loading_screen/Sandro Silva.ogg'`. Like this, `$music  = 'http://4late.nn.pe/loading_screen/Sandro Silva.ogg';`.

Comment: Your a savior! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing semicolon, in the if block:

```
if (strtolower($authors[$r]) == strtolower('Sandro Silva & Quintino - Epic (Original Mix)')) {
    $music  = 'http://4late.nn.pe/loading_screen/Sandro Silva.ogg';
}
```

Upper/Lower case the string before matching, just to make to rule out case inconsistencies.